# ES6 classes inheritance resolving conflicting method names

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-class

I want `this.method2()` call of `base` to execute `base.method2()` while it actually executes `derived.method2()` (I understand the idea behind the behavior), is it possible to achieve this *without methods renaming* and what is the best practice here?

```
const base = class {
      method() {
        this.method2();
      }

      method2() {
        console.error("base.method2");
      }
}

const derived = new class extends base {
      method() {
        super.method();
      }

      method2() {
        console.error("derived.method2");
      }
}

derived.method(); // want 'base.method2' here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `call`.

```
method() {
  base.prototype.method2.call(this);
}
```

In this case you don't technically *need* to use `call` and supply the `this` value, because you don't use it, but it is the best way to create the call you want so it works in all circumstances.

Incidentally, I don't understand what you are seeking to achieve with the `const base = class {}` statement. A class declaration would be much less surprising: `class base {}`.

Comment: Interestingly enough I tried getting it working by using different number of inputs for method2 of base & derived, and then call it from base with the base specific set of inputs - but even then it still called derived.method2 - isn't it counter-intuitive?

Comment: @Simple.Js No, JS does not have any kind of method overloading based on signature (including number of parameters).

Comment: @Simple.Js No, for several reasons. First, JS functions don't have to be called with the correct number of arguments: you can supply more or fewer than the declared number and it will work. More importantly, you can't even rely on the object in question being a `base` object or a subclass: with `call` it could be literally any object.